# Making a HttpClient request from a different Azure region

Tags: azure, dotnet-httpclient

I need to test the availability of my API from code, from a specific region (e.g. Asia Pacific or something). Does Azure provide some service / library which makes it possible to achieve something like this?

Note that I specifically need to do this from code and not from some tool.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, this would be something to achieve with an Application Insights URL ping test.

> The name *URL ping test* is a bit of a misnomer. These tests don't use Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP) to check your site's availability. Instead, they use more advanced HTTP request functionality to validate whether an endpoint is responding. They measure the performance associated with that response. They also add the ability to set custom success criteria, coupled with more advanced features like parsing dependent requests and allowing for retries.

More information: [Monitor availability with URL ping tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/monitor-web-app-availability)

Since you state

> Note that I specifically need to do this from code and not from some tool.

you probably need to deploy your code in multiple regions and run it from there. [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) feels like a fit for such a scenario because of its serverless nature: it's quick, simple and cheap to run occasionally.